# How are Angular2 apps deployed on web servers?

Tags: apache, angular

I have uploaded my angular2 app to an apache server, but is this the best way to do it? The page loads and everything works, but it seems a bit slow on the initial load.

Comment: If it's slow on initial load it not related how you deploy. Please provide more information about your application. How did you build? Do you use Ahead of time compilation or do you use platform-dynamic?

Comment: I am using platform-dynamic compilation, but are apache servers commonly used for deploying angular2 apps?

Comment: Any HTTP server is fine for Angular2. Try AoT compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an Apache server to deploy Angular 2.

Angular is just HTML, Javascript and CSS, so all you have to do once you get the app to work locally, is to put your files on the server and access `index.html` via the browser.

If you're concerned with slow loading, you need to look into bundling your app into a few files, or using Ahead-of-Time compiling.

Consider using a pre-built setup to make your deployment easier.

- [An example](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/README.md) with SystemJS and Gulp
- [An example](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/blob/master/README.md) with webpack

You could also create your own build tools by following the official instructions on [Ahead-of-Time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).